# Need help to implement demo application ionic with list navigate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and angular js application. Here is the thing what I want to develop.

1) I have one array of items which has been parsed from json file.  - Its done in one controller lets give it name "DataParseController"

2) Want to show this items such that per item one page with one next button if user click on next button then next item should be load, This should be happen till last index of array. - I have done this thing also.

Here is the 3rd thing which I want to do, but I do not know how can I do that.

3) Suppose,when application starts at that time first item will be load from array, (index=0), When user click on next button then I want to show one intermediate page before load second item, where I want to show all items as a list view and will indicate how many items has been reviewed by user. like this [**`CodePen`**](http://codepen.io/amrithyerramilli/pen/dorexv)

Here is my question is that how can share $scope between these two pages.

Lets take a example I am on first item so my index would be 0 as of now in "DataParseController" controller. When user click on next button then new page will load where I will show all items as like above codepen with grey checkbox where items are selected that has been visited by user. From here User can go to any item.

How can I implement this thing ? I already added ng-repeat but this is working fine for one page. Here I want to add one more page which is intermediate page.

Please help me logically how Can I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will help you better formulate your question so it is easier for people to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Wolf thanks for your input, I tried my best to explain my situation.